# Programatically finding if an alternative translation exists or not in a .resx file

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resx

I have a project that has translations in multiple .resx files.

e.g.

- Admin.resx
- Admin.fr.resx
- Admin.it.resx
- Admin.de.resx

Does anyone know of a way to programatically find out if a translation that exists in the default fallback,  doesn't exist in the alternative language file?

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
public static bool StringExistsInCulture(string key, CultureInfo ci)
{
   ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(Admin));
   string defaultString = resources.GetString(key, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   string transString = resources.GetString(key, ci);

   return (defaultString == transString);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when a translation is the same as in the default fallback, it'll return `true`, while the requested logic is to have it return `false`? Whether that's important or not, depends on the context of course...